# How do I validate my form within PHP via JQuery Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**How do I validate my code in PHP without getting error messages defined in the ajax definition in main.js?**

*Note: Chrome console returning:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Documents/Mini%20Revision%20Projects/Project%20Website%203/ajax.php. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.*

Below is my code:

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Documents\jQuery\jquery2.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body>

        <ul id="info1">
                <li>Put anything in the field below.</li>
        </ul>
        <form id="form1">
                <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>  

    </body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form1").submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //alert("happy");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#info1").html(data.msg);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Status: " + textStatus);
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
    class ajaxValidate {

            function formValidate() {
                    //Put form elements into post variables (this is where you would sanitize your data)
                    $field1 = @$_POST['field1'];

                    //Establish values that will be returned via ajax
                    $return = array();
                    $return['msg'] = '';
                    $return['error'] = false;

                    //Begin form validation functionality
                    if (!isset($field1) || empty($field1)){
                            $return['error'] = true;
                            $return['msg'] .= '<li>Error: Field1 is empty.</li>';
                    }

                    //Begin form success functionality
                    if ($return['error'] === false){
                            $return['msg'] = '<li>Success Message</li>';
                    }

                    //Return json encoded results
                    return json_encode($return);
            }

    }

    $ajaxValidate = new ajaxValidate;
    echo $ajaxValidate->formValidate();
?>
```

Comment: are you at least using any LAMP ? from the chrome error - I'm guessing  not...

Comment: @LorDex - I don't know what LAMP is unfortunately. I guess that answers the question :S.

Comment: you need to have PHP server in order to PHP scripts to work. install something like XAMPP (windows) or MAMP (linux)

Comment: @LorDex - I didn't have a PHP server. DOH! Put that as the answer please I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have PHP server in order to PHP scripts to work. install something like XAMPP (windows) or MAMP (linux)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, verify if PHP is not returning a warning or critical error. Insert this code in top of your code. If PHP returns a hidden error, the success data value will be null.

```
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

[PHP Error reporting manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

[PHP run-time display_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)

I think that if you are returning a JSON array in php, you need to call an array.

```
$("#info1").html(data['msg']);
```

Try to return the post values to verify if $_POST is not empty:

```
return json_encode($_POST);
```

You don't need to define an empty array if you define directly a first row.

```
//$return = array();
$return['msg'] = '';
```